# Working abs after regular workout

Tags: muscle, abdominals

A guy in my gym suggested not to work for abs after regular/other body part workout.

Reason was that, if you do abs after regular workout, muscles get loose and your workout will go waste.

How true it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like that guy doesn't know what he's talking about.  There's nothing wrong with working abs after another body part.

Answer (score 4):

The guy is wrong; depending on the exercises you've performed, your abs might already have been worked. 
 
 However, if you need to perform abs exercises along with your regular workout, they (abs exercises) should come last; otherwise, the soreness might affect your ability to perform your regular workout.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously there is no harm working out on abs everyday, as you stress it by your own bodyweight. But it is advisable to give a days rest to the abs incase you target the abdomianl area with external weights. for eg standing pulley crunches or crunches with weights on the chest, leg raises with weight pads etc

Comment: As your answer is now, it seems like you argue that there can be no harm from bodyweight exercises.

Comment: True as long as you don't over do stuff. Walking, running, pushups, crunches, pullups etc